# How to detect missiles collided with enemies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So once again I am trying to make a little shooting game where you have to dodge or shoot at enemies to win. The game is over once you get hit by an enemy and I managed to make that work. Yet my problem now is that I need a way to make it that once the enemy class and missiles class collide with each other they both disappear. But I couldn't figure a way to do that.

```
class Enemy(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pg.image.load("Enemy.png").convert()
        self.surf = pg.transform.smoothscale(self.surf, (75, 75))
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(5, 15)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
class Missile(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super(Missile, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pg.image.load("Missile.png").convert()
        self.surf = pg.transform.smoothscale(self.surf, (20, 20))
        self.surf.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center=pos)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(10, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Answer (score 2):

Call [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) on both objects when they collide. `kill` removes a sprite from all groups that contain it.

The collision can be detected with [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect). I the following `enemy` is an instance of `Enemy` and `missile` is an instance of `Missile`:

```py
if (pygame.sprite.collide_rect(enemy, missile):
    enemy.kill()
    missile.kill()
```

If you have a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) of `missiles` you can use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). When the *dokill* argument is `True`, the colliding missile will be *killed* automatically:

```py
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(enemy, missiles, True):
    enemy.kill()
```

If you have Group of `enemies` and a Group of `missiles`, you can use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). When either *dokill1* or *doKill2* is `True`, the corresponding object will be *killed* automatically:

```py
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemies, missiles, True, True)
```